# Runtime of startswith() in Python

Tags: python, performance, big-o

What is the runtime of startswith() method in Python?

Tried comparing this to ==. Wondering if it's the same big O.

Comment: Worst case would be _O(n)_ for sure, same as equality check.

Comment: Algorithmically, seeing if a string of length *n* starts with a string of length *k* requires only *O(k)* time. How it is in Python would depend on its implementation, but I would be very surprised if it is anything else.